# Apex parse error when creating SQL query with sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_a(BIDoctor number) RETURN number
IS
  num_a number;
BEGIN
  select count(NAppoint)
  into num_a
  from Appointment a
  where BIDoctor = a.BIDoctor;
  RETURN num_a;
END calc_a;
```

What we want is adding a column to a report that shows us the number of appointments that doc have.

```
select a.BIdoctor "NUM_ALUNO",
  a.NameP "Nome",
  a.Address "Local",
  a.Salary "salary",
  a.Phone "phone",
  a.NumberService "Curso",
  c.BIdoctor "bi",
  calc_media(a.BIdoctor) "consultas"
FROM "#OWNER#"."v_Doctor" a, "#OWNER#"."Appointment" c
WHERE a.BIdoctor = c.BIdoctor;
```

and we got this when we are writing the region source on apex. 
But it shows a parse error, I was looking for this about 2 hours and nothing.

Apex shows me this:

> PARSE ERROR ON THE FOLLOWING QUERY

Comment: Don't be shy.  Edit your question and include the error you are getting.

Comment: Are calc_a and calc_media the same function?

Comment: yup I got a error on that. after correcting appears:

Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist)

I have a got a v_Doctor view btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of all your double quotes, you seem to have randomly cased everything. Double quotes indicate that you're using quoted identifiers, i.e. the object/column must be created with that *exact* name - `"Hi"` is not the same as `"hi"`. Judging by your function **get rid of *all* the double quotes** - you don't seem to need them.

More generally don't use quoted identifiers. Ever. They cause far more trouble then they're worth. You'll know when you want to use them in the future, if it ever becomes necessary.

There are a few more problems with your SELECT statement.

- You're using implicit joins. Explicit joins were added in SQL-92; it's time to start using them - for your future career where you might interact with other RDBMS if nothing else.
- There's absolutely no need for your function; you can use the [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), [`COUNT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions039.htm#SQLRF00624) instead.
- Your aliases are a bit wonky - why does `a` refer to doctors and `c` to appointments?

Putting all of this together you get:

```
select d.bidoctor as num_aluno
     , d.namep as nome
     , d.address as local
     , d.salary as salary
     , d.phone as phone
     , d.numberservice as curso
     , a.bidoctor as bi
     , count(nappoint) over (partition by a.bidoctor) as consultas
  from #owner#.v_doctor a
  join #owner#.appointment c
    on d.bidoctor = a.bidoctor;
```

I'm guessing at what the primary keys of `APPOINTMENT` and `V_DOCTOR` are but I'm hoping they're `NAPPOINT` and `BIDOCTOR` respectively.

---

Incidentally, your function will never have returned the correct result because you haven't limited the scope of the parameter in your query; you would have just counted the number of records in `APPOINTMENT`. When you're naming parameters the same as columns in a table you have to explicitly limit the scope to the parameter in any queries you write, for instance:

```
select count(nappoint) into num_a
  from appointment a
 where calc_a.bidoctor = a.bidoctor; -- HERE
```

Comment: It cannot parse cause the character is invalid. I try this
select d.bidoctor as num_aluno , d.namep as nome
, d.address as local
, d.salary as salary
, d.phone as phone
, d.numberservice as curso
, c.bidoctor as bi
, count(nappoint) over (partition by c.bidoctor) as consultas
from #owner#.v_doctor d
join #owner#.appointment c
on d.bidoctor = c.bidoctor;

and it still give the error invalid character